# Is it possible to sort and delete images in the Mosaico gallery?

Tags: mosaico

I would like to be able to sort and remove some of the images in my Mosaico gallery but can't see an obvious way to do this - any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: This related question may help: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/34812/manage-the-image-gallery-in-mosaico

It looks like you can use the file browser in traditional mailings as a workaround.